# Hardcoded Dvorak Keyboard to Qwerty

Tags: keyboard, dvorak

So I purchased a UniComp keyboard and instead of rearranging the keys to try Dvorak I decided I would have them configure the Dvorak layout for me... I was happy with Dvorak at first but I need my typing speed back. Unfortunately, they hard coded it to Dvorak (why they would do this I do not know, as now I cant customise it to any other layout), I need a way to map the Dvorak layout to Qwerty. Preferably this would be through a programmable USB dongle but I would settle for software side. If this I use software, I would need a program for both Windows and Debian that does the mapping.

Comment: I imagine that you if do a manual mapping from dvorak to qwerty, that will work...

Comment: for windows https://www.randyrants.com/category/sharpkeys/ for debian https://github.com/kentonv/dvorak-qwerty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not afraid of opening the keyboard, you might look inside for a jumper or solder-short which chooses dvorak or qwerty layout.

At least that's what I'd look for.

Their prices are pretty low for a buckling spring keyboard, so I'd hazard a guess that the firmware of the keyboard is a jumper or short on the pc-board inside.  Remember everyone wants 'least expensive', so making the firmware flip between two mapping tables would be my guess.

You'd have to pop off all the relevant keys and rearrange them, this is Fun!  Especially if you can engage a young child to do the keycap replacements. (I had to pay an outrageous cookie fee though)

Comment: I'll try this later this evening. If it works I'll accept your answer :-D Thanks for the tip!

Comment: It's mostly just based on my experience with companies and engineers... just consider them all lazy, looking to make things easier (not that they are thus really).  Cheaper to make a pc board with a switch than to make two separate boards, or make custom roms for a (possibly rare) custom request.

Comment: Best answer may be delayed on this one... Taking apart the keyboard requires a socket set which I don't have... Rest assured when I am able to test this out, if it works I will select yours.

Comment: @retrohacker: Any update on this?